# Accessing a specific argument from a Variable Argument List in C

Tags: c

For example, I'd like to access the 6th argument, which has a value of 6:

```
int myfun(int count, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    int 6th_arg;

    va_start(ap, count); 

    // 6th_arg = va_arg(ap*sizeof(int)*5, int);

    va_end(ap);                

    return 6th_arg; // return 6
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", myfun(10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10));
}
```

Comment: Just call `va_arg` 6 times in a loop.

Comment: Best practice: _don't_ use variadic functions at all, but pass along an array and size. Random access, instant access, type safe, readable. Don't use language features just because they are available. A significant portion of the C language is unfortunately dangerous trash; the headers stdarg.h and stdio.h in particular.

Comment: Thanks Lundin. I'll try avoiding variadic functions and use the array technique instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `va_arg` macro always gets the next argument in the list.

If you want to read the 6th argument, you first need to read the 5 that come before it.

Comment: Would be nice if C could allow ap[5] syntax, similar to how arrays are accessed without having to read all elements that came before it. Thanks!